# Free Shipping shopping cart rule based on discounted subtotal

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping

I know there are other instances of this questions strewn about on this stack, but I haven't found a clear and defined answer.

I currently have a free shipping shopping cart rule created. I have to use this method instead of the free shipping section under the config/shipping section of the admin since I have to exclude Hawaii & Alaska from receiving the free shipping. The rule is set to work on USA based orders with a subtotal of $75 or greater. Works perfectly fine, however, if someone also uses a discount code that puts them below the $75 threshold, it still applies the free shipping.

ex. Customer has a subtotal of $80 and then applies a 10% discount code, putting their subtotal at $72, magento still gives them free shipping since it's looking at the subtotal pre-discount.

I'm using 1.9.1 currently, how can I fix this easily? I'd rather not touch any core files, since I don't want to have to fix this anytime Magento gets upgraded.

Answer (score -2):

Try to insert minimum order amount in free shipping method configuration from backend.

Comment: I can't use the free shipping method config from the backend, because it then allows the free shipping to Hawaii and Alaska customers, which I can't due to cost.

Comment: Remove cart rule completely and use table rate shipping instead of this, table rate shipping allows you to specify shipping rule to be applied for certain area and with certain condition like as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: That method still won't work for me.